# List of Maths Operations ordered by instruction cycle length by computational load?

Tags: performance

Is there somewhere a list of how many cycles different maths operations take, for a typical processor like an intel q6600, the performance varies abit from between processors although it would be very informative to have a graph /  a list, did anyone see one somewhere?

i.e.:

```
math.sqr = 27 cycles
math.sin = 22 cycles
divide = 8 cycles
modulo = 4 cycles
compare a>b = 2 cycles
multiply = 1 cycles
```

Something like that?

how many cycles do different comparisons use?

Comment: u mean like the doco?

Comment: Oh okay nice one i found this document on page 764 has a list http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel would be the source for that:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Answer (score 4):

A rather complete list for Kentsfield (includes Q6600) can be found [here](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00006F7_Kentsfield_DDR3_InstLatX86.txt).

That is, however, not enough. The time a sequence of instructions takes is not (usually) simply the sum of its parts - several things can usually execute at once, and determining which things they are takes some effort. I recommend you read the relevant chapter of [Microarchitecture (by Agner Fog)](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) and you'll need [this](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) to see which execution ports the instructions can go to.

If you're just looking for rule-of-thumb numbers, here they are (1c .33t means a latency of 1 cycle and a reciprocal throughput of .33 ie 3 independent ones can execute in a cycle:

- integer addition/subtraction/compare/bitwise: 1c .33t
- integer multiplication: 5c 1t
- integer division 32bit: 30-60c 20-40t
- integer division 64bit: 40-70c 30-40t
- integer shift: 1c 0.5t
- float add: 3c 1t
- float multiply: 5c 1t
- square root: 6-70c
- sine, cosine: 100c